# How do you simulate a drag event (mousemove with a button clicked)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to be able to trigger the event and have it show that there was actually a button that was down at the time the event was fired.

```
$('table').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var is_dragging = e.buttons.length > 0;
  // is_dragging should === true;
});

$('table').trigger('mousemove'); // is_dragging will be false
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Please read [MCVE].

Comment: Usually `mousemove` is attached in `mousedown` handler to emulate dragging, hence no need to check if "dragging" is on. Please explain in more details, what you actually need.

Comment: @Anders I updated the code to show the issue I'm having

Comment: @Teemu I want to be able to trigger the event and have it show that there was actually a button that was `down` at the time the event was fired.

Comment: I think you need to be binding to `mousedown` event instead of `mousemove`. That said, seems like you need to add `buttons` property to the event that you are triggering. For that you need to create a custom event and add the property to that event.

Comment: @Sachin How do I create a custom event?

Comment: @Teemu Updated, sorry about that

Comment: Can't you just lie, i.e. set `is_dragging = true;`? Or if you're going to use the actual `e.buttons` you could use a variable with a suitable value instead.

Comment: @Teemu Hah, I actually depend on that `is_dragging` variable by executing some logic when it's true. I'm writing a test based on the "`drag`" event to make sure that the logic that is executed is correct.

Comment: @DanielPatz Check my answer for the custom event. That should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out. Creating a custom event and attaching `buttons` property to it.

```
$('table').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var is_dragging = e.buttons.length > 0;
  // is_dragging should === true;
});

var e = $.Event( 'mousemove' );
e.buttons = ['<set any key you need>'];

$('table').trigger(e);
```

Comment: Awesome, that did it! Here is the jsfiddle to prove it works: https://jsfiddle.net/vf1o5cws/1/

Answer (score 1):

So based on what i think you are trying to accomplish. You want to have an event handler for onmousemove where you are checking to see if a button is down (doesn't matter which button is down) however you want to manually trigger the event and have the condition is_dragging result in true.

If the event is manually triggered using `$('table').trigger('mousemove');`the event will not have a buttons property however it will have a .isTrigger property which will == 3.

**Try this:**
https://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/L2z0su3j/

```
$('table').on('mousemove', function(e) {
  var is_dragging = e.buttons > 0 || e.buttons == undefined && e.isTrigger == 3;
  // is_dragging should === true;
  $('p').html(is_dragging.toString())
});

$('#trigger').click(function(){

    $('table').trigger('mousemove');

})
```

Answer (score 0):

**::UPDATE::**

look into `ondragstart`
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragstart.asp

=======

`*.buttons` is for what button you have clicked. At the time of `mousemove` you have not clicked a button.

Meaning your `e.buttons === 0`

**Documentation on MouseEvent.button:** 
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_button.asp

You can verify this by throwing a `debugger` in your function and inspecting your `e` variable

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qf3u8m61/

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to emulate [`event.buttons`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/drag) in a mousemove handler.

Comment: I do, I don't really care which buttons are clicked as long as a button is down and the `mousemove` event was triggered

Comment: Oh i see what you're asking now... you're not being very clear in your post

Comment: **Update:** look into ondragstart http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragstart.asp